# What is the most cost-effective way to automatically start an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I am an Azure rookie. Currently, I have a small cheap VM that is always running, from which I start a big expensive VM via command line (i.e. a simple `az vm start -g foo -n bar`). However, I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this. Do you have any suggestions?

**Important**: it should not cost more than 5$/month. My current setup is 'free' because I need the small cheap VM to be running anyway.

I tried the [Microsoft's Start/Stop VMs v2 function](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoftcorporation1620879115842.startstopv2?tab=Overview), which is [recommended by Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/start-stop-vms/overview). Before deploying it, I tried to figure out the projected cost of this solution. Here is a summary of the components and their prices.

- Functions: [Pricing - Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/#pricing) - the functions have a free monthly buffer of 400kGB-s and 1Mio. executions.
- Logic App: [Pricing - Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/logic-apps/#pricing) - free for our purposes under Consumption Plan
- Storage: [Azure Files Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/files/#pricing) - monthly storage costs will be < 1$ as the Start/Stop VM function should need < 1GiB
- Networking: [Pricing - Bandwidth](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/#pricing) - monthly networking costs will be < 1$ as the transferred data size is low for this function
- Application Insights: [Pricing - Azure Monitor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/)
- Monitor: see Application Insights
- Dashboard: Unclear, maybe this [Pricing - Stream Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/stream-analytics/#pricing)

Looks great, a neat and elegant solution for 5$/month, exactly what I need, right?
**BUT**: after deploying the function and monitoring the costs, it turns out that the Storage account is by default protected by the [Microsoft Defender for Cloud](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/defender-for-cloud/), which was not mentioned anywhere before. This one alone costs over 10$/month. The security layer is of course important. I don't want to sound cheap but those costs accumulate over time and will increase further when scaling up or out.

Thus, back to my question: What would you suggest as the best practice to automatically start/stop a virtual machine in Azure?

Maybe there is another elegant solution that doesn't require navigating through Microsoft's pricing maze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Azure Automation`  to automate the Azure resources using runbooks and create a PowerShell runbooks to **start** and **stop** your VM on a schedule by following below steps.

1. Create a [Automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/quickstarts/create-azure-automation-account-portal#create-automation-account) with `System Identity`
2. Create a **Runbook** in automation account by navigating to `Runbooks > Create a runbook`

[image]

3. Open **Runbook >  Edit in Portal > add below script  and click on Publish**

You can find the automation account `object ID` here.

[image]

> Note: The Identity must have the `Virtual Machine Contributor` role assigned to start/Stop the VM

```
 az login --identity --username "Automation Identity object ID"
 az vm start --name "Venkat-VM" --no-wait --resource-group "VM_RG_Name"
```

4. **Schedules the runbook > add a schedule > link schedule to your run book > Create.**

[image]

The **VM** has been automatically started according to the scheduled time.

[image]

5. To **stop a virtual machine**, you can use the default `Auto-shutdown` option in the VM settings.

[image]

Comment: The stop also can be a runbook. But yes, I think this is the best, most beautiful and simplest solution.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and the relevant suggestion.

Comment: Great, an automation runbook is the best solution for your scenario.